# Installing phantomjs by puppet on a vagrant VM doesn't work

Tags: npm, phantomjs, vagrant, puppet, sudo

I try with the to install phanomjs on a vagrant machine (Ubuntu Trusty 64bit) with the following puppet command:

```
exec {"npm install -g phantomjs":
    path => "/usr/bin",
    require => [
        Package["nodejs-legacy"]
    ]
}
```

This results in the following error (from /home/vagrant/npm-debug.log)

```
...
2550 info install request@2.36.0
2551 info postinstall request@2.36.0
2552 verbose about to build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs
2553 info build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs
2554 info install phantomjs@1.9.7-14
2555 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle false
2556 error Error: spawn ENOENT
2556 error     at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
2556 error     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
2557 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
2557 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
2557 error or email it to:
2557 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
2558 error System Linux 3.13.0-30-generic
2559 error command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phantomjs" "--no-bin-links"
2560 error cwd /home/vagrant
2561 error node -v v0.10.25
2562 error npm -v 1.3.10
2563 error syscall spawn
2564 error code ENOENT
2565 error errno ENOENT
2566 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

same from console

[image]

Why is this happening? What is wrong? If I install the package manually by

```
vagrant ssh
sudo npm install -g phantomjs
```

it works fine.

Comment: It looks like you're using sudo via ssh but not in puppet?

Answer (score 2):

You should carefully compare the environment of your successful invocation with what Puppet uses - the `path` you specify looks insufficient for most tasks, because binaries in `/bin` won't be found.

You probably want to get the [nodejs module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/nodejs) instead, so that you can use the `npm` provider for the `package` type like

```
package { 'phantomjs':
    provider => 'npm',
    ensure   => 'present',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with ubuntu server 14.04 with vagrant/puppet provisioning node + npm. Although it's not clearly the same situation from your log, it might be something you want to give it a shot.

it seems there is a change of package naming on ubuntu for nodejs. From **node** to **nodejs**. Below from my log (using vagrant and puppet provisionner)

```
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
```

doing a few research, I settled on creating a symlink (seems the most popular hack)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

My Puppet site.pp looks like this:

```
include nodejs

# Exec path
Exec {
  path => [
    '/usr/bin',
    '/bin',
    'sbin'],
  logoutput => true,
}

# quickfix the bug with ubuntu changing the bin name from node to nodejs
exec { 'ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node':}

# Configure Docroot
file { ['/var/www', '/var/www/dev','/prj']:
ensure => directory,
owner => 'vagrant',
group => 'vagrant',
mode => '775'
}

#for global packages
package { 'grunt-cli':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => 'npm',
}

package { 'bower':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => 'npm',
}

package { 'supervisor':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => 'npm',
}

package { 'codebox':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => 'npm',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should include tar file path too.
below code worked for me.

```
exec {"sudo rm -rf ~/tmp;sudo npm install -g phantomjs":
  path => "/usr/bin:/bin/tar",
  provider => "shell"
}
```